# Is there a way to link a bitcoin user's transaction to entering a lightning network channel?

Tags: transactions, privacy, lightning-network, tracking, chainanalysis

Since lightning channels are offchain. When you send bitcoins to a lightning network node or wallet. Is there a way for companies like chainalysis to see if your on the lightning network? And then from there track your coin movements there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way for companies like chainalysis to see if your on the lightning network?

Not really. Funding a channel will look just like sending coins to a P2WSH address. Closing a channel cooperatively also just looks like that P2WSH address sending to two addresses. This does not tell any outside observer that you are actually using the Lightning Network.

> And then from there track your coin movements there?

Coin movements over LN are not easily trackable since not all LN nodes see all LN transactions.

Comment: So if a large payment channel like coinbase or some other big exchange opens up a lightning channel and it never closes. You can technically have anonymous bitcoin transactions assuming someone comes up with offchain privacy features?

Comment: I believe that is the case.